# Stepper motor - optimal voltage when using a chopper driver

Tags: stepper-motor

When running stepper motors with a chopper driver, the motor voltage applied is much higher than what the motor is rated for, because the chopper is a current source.
The question however is, what voltage to use in order to get the maximum performance out of the motor (for example, to get the holding torque the motor claims to have)?

I came across the following formula in some forum (without explanation provided)

```
Vmax = SQRT(inductance) * 32
```

So that would mean that if I'm using some stepstick stepper drivers that support a maximum of 36V I should look for stepper motors with inductance below (36/32)^2=1.26mH, otherwise I won't be able to run them at their rated performance (of course they also should be rated for current less than the maximum RMS current of the stepper).

```
1. Is this correct?
2. Where does this formula come from? Why 32?
```

Comment: Unless you know the assumptions (if any) to produce that formula, then don’t use it. Do some more research...

Comment: That is what I am doing here

Comment: We are not a free research tool...

Comment: I think my question is pretty concise and of interest to everyone who runs stepper motors with chopper drivers, so I don‘t think this question is misplaced. I could add though: if the formula is wrong, how do I compute optimal supply voltage when using chopper drivers?

Comment: Data sheet of the stepper motor or the driver?

Comment: And did I say that the formula is wrong? I just sId if you don’t know the assumptions....

Comment: This is general - I haven‘t picked a specific motor OR driver yet. The info that is usually available for stepper motors is: Current rating, phase inductance, stepping angle. Chopper drivers have max current and max voltage ratings. Or are you saying these parameters are insufficient to compute supply voltage at which the motors reach their macimum rated performance? If so, what additional info is needed?

Comment: I think the best source of info for this will be the various charts in the driver datasheet. There will probably be a few with input voltage on the x axis. My intuition is that the motor will probably not be effected.